# Is it possible to deploy PHP application on azure (WebApps) without using FTP?

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service

Hi i have recently deploy my PHP(5.4) application to windows azure i.e.Web Apps.For that purpose I have used FTP to transfer my local files to azure.

Is there is any wayout so that I can just click and publish my PHP application to Azure like what we do in .net VS application (Right click publish) ?

Comment: PHP can be transferred over FTP.

Comment: This is called Continuous Integration and it is possible through Jenkins, Travis-CI and so on. Usually you should consider using GIT or SVN to commit changes in your codebase.

Comment: You could use dropbox ;) http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/03/19/new-deploy-to-windows-azure-web-sites-from-dropbox/

Comment: Thanks Jay,Linial,AmeRie :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned in comments, there are several continuous-integration sources for deployment. Assuming you're using the new portal (portal.azure.com), just pull up your web app and scroll down below **Essentials**. Near the bottom, you'll see the area about continuous deployments. If you haven't set it up yet, you'll see something asking you to set it up. Click, and then choose your source:

[image: CI setup]

Once you set this up, you should be able to manage your deployments by simply pushing code to your repository.